# Access denied error on aws s3 when uploading a file from an ec2 instance that is on a different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have this instance I recently launched. I want to upload an Image file to s3. But whenever I try to access the uploaded file, I get the error:

`AccessDenied`
Access Denied

Everytime a file is uploaded, I am saving the file url in database. I then paste that url in the browser. Then it gives me the error. When uploaded from local server, that url simply downloads the file (in this case an Image).

Here is the policy permissions

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname>/*"
    }
]
```

}

When I upload a file from local server, it works fine. When I upload a file from the instance that belongs to same user as s3 bucket. It works fine. This particular instance isn't created using the same account as s3 bucket. I don't know if that is a problem or not.

Comment: You will need to provide permission to access the bucket. Have you assigned an IAM Role to the Amazon EC2 instance? If so, then you could add that IAM Role to the Bucket Policy on the Amazon S3 bucket, to permit it to `PutObject`. Alternatively, you could take the IAM User credentials that you have been using on your 'local server' and put them on the EC2 instance.

Comment: Warning: The policy you have shown above will make your bucket 'public', so that anyone who knows the Key (filename) will be able to access your bucket. Be careful with any data you put in such a bucket.

Comment: So, The first thing I did was used the same credentials on the EC2 instance. `aws s3api list-buckets --query "Owner.ID"` and `aws sts get-caller-identity` command both return same ids. After your suggestion, I added the IAM role to the bucket policy. However the result is still same.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are accessing the file via a URL in a web browser. This should work fine with the Bucket Policy you have shown in your question, since it is making the bucket public.

If you are uploading the file from credentials that belong to a *different* AWS Account, then you should use `ACL=public-read` when doing the upload. This will grant ownership of the object to the account that owns the bucket.